How to deal with mismatched craft land plugin licence when staging in on a different domain
So i have a work flow likethis:
local->staging->production
local is my domain.test
staging is subdomain.kitbox.com
production is productiondomain.com
How can i stop licence warnings or add test domains? Craft console doesn't seem to allow this

This might sound easier than you expect but I use a custom domain (subdomain.accpt.nl) for staging/acceptance as well and the solution is to just contact Pixel & Tonic.
See the note at the bottom of this paragraph: https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/how-craft-license-enforcement-works#how-do-we-determine-craft-is-running-on-a-public-domain They have an internal list with domains that are used for staging websites and can add you to this list. It might take a day or two.

You can find all the info on License Enforcement in the Knowledge Base. This applies both to the Craft license as well as any plugin licenses.
Your local .test domain won't show license warnings by default, since it's not a standard TLD (exclusion rule #5).
For your staging environments, you need a 'dev-sounding' subdomain. You can use something like client-staging.kitbox.com, as only part of the subdomain (split at the word boundary) needs to match one of the subdomains in the list (exclusion rule #4).
We prefer to use something like staging.our-clients-domain.tld so it feels 'closer to home' for our clients than a random staging domain. But it's up to you as long as you use a subdomain from the list in the article linked above.
